# ASP.NET ChangePassword Control Stopped Working

Tags: asp.net, authentication, webforms, forms-authentication, adam

We have a couple of ASP.NET WebForms applications that use the ADAM Membership provider, one of which includes the ChangePassword control. The control has started to fail every password change:

```
Password incorrect or New Password invalid. 
New Password length minimum: 6. 
Non-alphanumeric characters required: 0.
```

We can still successfully reset passwords on the ADAM instance, and the logins still authenticate in the applications. There are no exceptions thrown, and no errors in EventViewer.

Here is the provider section of the Web.config:

```
        <membership defaultProvider="ADAMMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="ADAMMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
         connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" 
         connectionProtection="None" 
         connectionUsername="[the username]" 
         connectionPassword="[the password]" 
         enableSearchMethods="true" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3"
         passwordAttemptWindow="5"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="true"/>
    </providers>
   </membership>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that ADAM does not allow passwords to be changed over insecure connections by default.  There are couple ways around this problem:

- Setting your connectionProtection property to "Secure" and having the necessary SSL certificates in place.

or

- Using [dsmgmt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781970%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and changing the "Ds Behavior" to "Allow passed op on unsecured connection".